# calc CSS for col tag

Tags: html, css

**** UPDATED ****
I found out if I just leave off the last width then it auto fills to the end of the table... why?  No idea, but I guess its just how it works?

---

Here is my fiddle:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e8qe6gxL/1/)

```
<div>
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Maybe</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
th, td { outline: 1px solid red;}
table {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}
col:first-child { width: 35px; }
col:nth-child(2) { width: 35%; }
col:last-child { width: calc(65% - 35px); }
```

There is a difference in safari vs chrome. I think in Safari it doesn't calculate the last one because I even changed it to 25% - 35 and it still filled the width. More than anything I just want to see where the differences are documented. Or if someone wants to explain how they treat them so I don't make this mistake again (btw, the original code works great in chrome... but noticed today in safari the last column was completely collapsed which is what got me investigating)

Comment: I don't have Safari here, so I can't check, but I'm curious. What exactly IS the difference?

Comment: Anyway, if all the widths can be calculated (the width of the table is known, so the last column can be inferred from the rest of the columns) it doesn't NEED a value for its width. In fact, a value that would cause a mismatch (e.g. table 300px, two columns 200px each) would be handled by the browsers in a way that is implementation dependent. That is, some browsers may handle this by ignoring the last column's width property.